# Asyns/Await loading large files into the datagrid

Tags: c#

I know I am more than likely doing something wrong here, I'm trying to use the async method to load data from a file into a `DataGridView`, some files can be 100,000 lines long so the UI freezes if I do it the non-async way.

My code so far is pretty basic.

**Code:**

```
public async Task OnLoadDataGridDataIntoView(string theSynFile) {
    try {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            string[] synFile = File.ReadAllLines(theSynFile);
            foreach (string synEntry in synFile)
            {
                DataGridSynonymsView.Rows.Add(synEntry);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ClassHelpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
    }
}

private async void ComboBoxSynonymFile_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await OnLoadDataGridDataIntoView(ComboBoxSynonymFile.Text);
    ClassHelpers.ReturnMessage("Done!");
}
```

The way the code is now nothing is loaded into the datagridview, do I need to even await `await OnLoadDataGridDataIntoView(ComboBoxSynonymFile.Text);` if there is nothing being returned as such?

I'm still trying to find my way around the async/await methods, I'm a bit rusty any help in the right direction would be great.

Comment: If the idea is that you still want the UI to be responsive while this stuff is loading, you should not use `await` in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event, or any UI event for that matter. Using `await` here means your method won't return until it's done loading. Since it doesn't return, the UI can't update. Since the UI can't update, it freezes. Don't use `await` here. If you need something to happen when the method ends, you can use things like [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0) or callbacks.

Comment: Uh, no. When you use `await`, your async function returns right after whatever you are awaiting starts. It will restart (asynchronously) when whatever you started finishes. You need to know that using `Task.Run` means you are dispatching your work to a threadpool thread. That thread can't update your UI (bad things happen if you try). You may want to take advantage of the asynchronously  nature of I/O and read asynchronously from the file system, not using `File.ReadAllLines`. Sorry, not near a computer, so I can't come up with an answer

Comment: The System.IO namespace has plenty of asynchronous variants to read the content of files, pick one and await it. What you cannot do is to update a Control from a Thread other than the UI Thread (so you probably have set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` somewhere, to avoid the exception <- just *hides* the problem). Make your async method return a collection that can be set as the DataSource of your grid

Comment: Is it WinForms? Add tag.

Comment: To work with a large amount of data, you must use [virtual mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be slow any way you do it, if you are adding rows one at a time

Try adding all rows at once, something like:

```
string[] synFile = File.ReadAllLines(theSynFile);
DataGridSynonymsView.Rows.AddRange(synFile);
```